# Playing DTMF tones into a call

Tags: tokbox, vonage, dtmf

We're trying to determine a way to send DTMF into the call. As we understand, It's only possible by using this Vonage API -> https://developer.nexmo.com/api/voice?theme=dark#play-dtmf. But initiating a call using TokBox API -> "v2/project/{this.ApiKey}/dial"
does not provide call "leg UUID" in response.
There are only these properties in response:

`{ "id": UUID, "connectionId": UUID, "streamId": UUID }`

Is there any way to get leg UUID from TokBox/Nexmo API call response or by any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few weeks later we figured that out. The trick is in calling on your own number from TokBox, then using webhook; we're getting call details and calling to 3rd party from Nexmo by adding a new member to a conference. TokBox -> SIP-conference.

This hack is undocumented and strips a lack of feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send DTMF using the OpenTok SDK, but you should be able to join that call using the Voice API. Perhaps join the call server side as a "ghost" participant.

If your backend has joined the call, you could expose an HTTP endpoint that you call from your frontend with the DTMF tone to send in.

I haven't done that myself, but in theory it should work.

Comment: we are able to connect sip to video as a "ghost". Works perfectly but OpenTok creates a cross-service connection under the hood and doesn't share a connection from/to UUIDs. Without them, we are not able to play the DTMF/audio stream  into that call which is required because the other side is behind IVR and expects PIN and then additional number

Answer (score -1):

if you had access to the AT command sets, you could send the modem the following standard AT command:

AT+VTS="0123456789#*ABCD", 10

That command asks the modem to play for 1 second all the 16 DTMF tones.

It works. I used it several times in the past.

Enrico Migliore

Comment: Hi Enrico. Sorry but your answer is not relevant to TokBox/Nexmo services.